# Create a "file.dat" from the windows CMD

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, gnuplot

When running the following C ++ script I obtain the necessary data to work in Gnuplot.

```
#include "stdio.h"

double TT;/* Imaginary part of T matrix */
double x;/* Real part of Energy */
double y;/* Imaginary part of Energy */
double G;/*Resonance Peak width */
double ER;/* Resonance Peak Energy */

main()
{
G = 120.;
ER=180.;
for(x=150.;x<=200.;x=x+1.){
for(y=-70.;y<=-50.;y=y+0.5){

/* Plotting T as a function of x and y */
TT = (G/2.)*(y+(G/2.))/(ER*ER - 2.*ER*x + G*y + (G*G/4.) + x*x + y*y);
printf("%g %2.1f %f\n", x,y,TT); /*Printing out T to standard output*/
}
printf("\n"); /* printing a newline after every column(this part is crutial) */
}
}
```

from the command Prompt I run the following command line:

```
.\3D_Data start notepad++ > mytextfile.dat
```

When calling the point DAT file in Gnuplot
I get the following Alert:

```
gnuplot> splot 'mytextfile.dat'
         warning: Bad data on line 1 of file mytextfile.dat
         Not enough input columns
```

If the content of the file is copied and inserted into a new file within Notepad ++ and saved with extension Dat; then it runs correctly in Gnuplot
[image]

I have tried with these command lines without any results

```
// C:\projects\helloworld> .\3D_Data ./a.out > 3Ddata
// PS C:\projects\helloworld> .\3D_Data > result.txt
// PS C:\projects\helloworld> .\3D_Data | Out-File -FilePath .\OUTPUT.txt
// PS C:\projects\helloworld> .\3D_Data test.exe > myoutput.txt
// PS C:\projects\helloworld> .\3D_Data copy > SN.txt
// PS C:\projects\helloworld> .\3D_Data echo > filename2.txt
// C:\projects\helloworld> .\3D_Data /S > Myfile.dat
```

something I have noticed is that the file created from Notepad ++ is almost twice small in size.

Is it possible to get a file from the CMD that is accepted by Gnuplot functions?

```
G N U P L O T
         Version 5.4 patchlevel 1 last modified 2020-12-01
```

Comment: To nitpick a little, there's really nothing specific to C++ in that source, it could be built as a plain C program.

Comment: As for your problem, is the `.\3D_Data` program your program (built from the shown source)? Then `.\3D_Data > result.txt` should be correct. Have you checked the created `result.txt` file? Does it follow the format specified for the GNUPlot `splot` command? Have you tried to use the name `result.dat` instead of `result.txt`?

Comment: C++ is not a scripting language, and this is not a script. It is a program. Don't misuse standard terminology. And please format this illegible mess properly.

Comment: [I am unable to reproduce.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTNyY.png) You simply need to compile your file (`g++ filename.cc`) and then run it as `./a.exe 1>result.dat` (in windows it is **not** a.out). Then open `gnuplot` and run this as command `splot "absolute/path/to/your/file/result.dat"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the code you use looks more like C and not C++.
(which is fine too)

In C, you can use fprinf instead of printf .. have a look here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   FILE *file;
   const double G = 120.;
   const double ER=180.;

   file = fopen("file.dat","w+");//create or overwrites a file
   
   for(int x=150; x<=200; x++){
      for(double y=-70.; y<=-50.; y += 0.5){
         TT = (G/2.)*(y+(G/2.))/(ER*ER - 2.*ER*x + G*y + (G*G/4.) + x*x + y*y);
         fprintf(file,"%g %2.1f %f\n", x, y, TT); //writes into a file
      }
      fprintf(file,"\n");//same here
   }

   fclose(file);//flushes the file and closes it
   return(0);
}
```

In C++, you can use fstream instead of printf .. have a look here:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <format>

int main () {
   
   std::ofstream file("file.dat", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);

   const double G =  120.;
   const double ER = 180.;
   
   for(int x=150; x<=200; x++){
      for(double y=-70.; y<=-50.; y += 0.5){
         TT = (G/2.)*(y+(G/2.))/(ER*ER - 2.*ER*x + G*y + (G*G/4.) + x*x + y*y);
         file << x << " " << std::format("{:2.1f}",y) << TT << "\n"; //writes into a file // EDIT: I added the C++20 std::format
      }
      file << std::endl;//same here
   }

   file.close();//flushes the file and closes it
   return(0);
}
```

Some tipps:

- Ty to fix all warnings (you should have had some)
- Try to do proper spaces and indentations!
- make variable names readable
- try to make source code that a human can read (without comments if possible)
- try to make functions that express your calculations

EDIT: I changed the command int the C++ example to std::format(..), as I had an error in the code.

Comment: have tried all the files generated with each of the CMDs shown; and with the extensions txt and DAT. I try to reproduce the example of this link:
[http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/~landaur/nacphy/DATAVIS/gnuplot.html](http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/~landaur/nacphy/DATAVIS/gnuplot.html)

Comment: ```C:\projects\C_Runner\Visualization_3D_Data.cpp:22:38: error: 'putf' is not a member of 'std'
             file << x << " " << std::putf("%2.1f", y) << TT << "\n";```

Comment: Yes I just changed the error. Sorry, std::putf was proposed but "only" std::format got introduced in C++20.

Comment: ```3D_Data_2.cpp:3:10: fatal error: format: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <format>
      |          ^~~~~~~~  ```
VS Code 1.56.0
What extension should I update or install in order to run C ++ 20?

Answer (score 0):

```
TT(x,y) = (G / 2.) * (y + (G / 2.)) / (ER * ER - 2. * ER * x + G * y + (G * G / 4.) + x * x + y * y)
ER=180.
G = 120.
set table 'test3D.dat'
splot [150:200] [-70:-50.1] TT(x,y)
unset table
splot 'test3D.dat' with lines
```

[image]